# Add text to <input> element but don't delete it

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have an `<input>` html element.
The element is filled by default value.
User should be able to append new text at the end of default text but could not delete default value.
How could I solve this problem?

Comment: I would display the default text as text _before_ the `<input>` and make the input optional. You can use CSS to give the text the appreance as it would be directly conected to the `<input>` field.

Comment: Would definetly be the best solution. Else you need to check on pressUp and then see if the input string contains "default value", if not replace the content with "default value".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with JavaScript:

```
listen('load', window, init);

function init() {
  var test = document.getElementById('test');
  var val = test.value;
  listen('keydown', test, replaceVal);
  listen('keyup', test, replaceVal);
  function replaceVal() {
    tempVal = test.value;
    if (tempVal.indexOf(val) === -1) {
      tempVal = val;
      test.value = val;
    }
  }
}

function listen(event, elem, func) {
  if (elem.addEventListener) {
    elem.addEventListener(event, func, false);
  } else if (elem.attachEvent) {
    elem.attachEvent('on' + event, func);   
  }
}
```

I have set up a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/sjfwz/
​

Answer (score 0):

try this

script :

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function MyFunction() {

        document.getElementById('TextBox3').value = document.getElementById('defaultValue').value;

        //if asp:textbox control should be work below
        document.getElementById('<%=TextBox4.ClientID%>').value = document.getElementById('defaultValue').value;

    }

</script>
    }


<body onLoad="javascript:MyFunction();">
<input type="hidden" id="defaultValue" name="defaultValue" value="defaultValue"/>
<input type="text" id="TextBox3" />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also compare the input value to a regex pattern on keydown event. You can then deny the keypress, for instance a backspace, if the regex didn't match.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do some complex JS you could just use background images with some padding.